# BadYieldError in tornado.gen when using Corduroy couchdb async library

Tags: python, couchdb, tornado

I'm trying to use [Corduroy](https://github.com/samizdatco/corduroy) to talk to a CouchDB asynchronously using the python [Tornado Web Server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/).

The code below comes from the [Corduroy guide](http://samizdat.cc/corduroy/guide/), with a couple of alterations.

```
import tornado.web
from corduroy import Database, NotFound, relax

people_db = Database('people')

class RelaxedHello(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @relax
    def get(self, user_id):
        try:
            doc = yield people_db.get(user_id)
            self.write('hello %s'%(doc['name']))
        except NotFound:
            self.write('hello whoever you are')
        self.finish()

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/hi/([^/]+)', RelaxedHello),
]).listen(1920)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The problem I'm having is that I receive a BadYieldError despite finding the couch document perfectly well. I suspect it's something to do with the tornado.gen module not being set up properly (or something?). Using corduroy without the @relax decorator, and with a callback works fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\env\pymeals_tornado\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1074, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\env\pymeals_tornado\lib\site-packages\corduroy\__init__.py", line 43,  in _r_e_l_a_x_
    return gen.engine(_func_)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\env\pymeals_tornado\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 107, in wrapper
    runner.run()
  File "c:\env\pymeals_tornado\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 319, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "test.py", line 10, in get
    doc = yield people_db.get(user_id)
BadYieldError: yielded unknown object <Document 65d936ee54417e46479a908f7a0038ef[2] {name:Colin}>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `gen` module directly?

Comment: Not yet. I'm still learning Tornado, and haven't used it before. I might have a play with it later, thanks!

Comment: Using the gen module directly yields good results, however I'd still like to try with corduroy. Investigating again this evening...

Comment: I'm not sure about quality of @relax decorator. Try to dig into it's code and understand what features of tornado it is using.

Comment: The @relax decorator looks like it just replaces using both asynchronous and tornado.gen.engine decorators. However, I still have to use "doc = yield tornado.gen.Task(people_db.get, user_id)" to do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the code for relax](https://github.com/samizdatco/corduroy/blob/master/corduroy/__init__.py#L26) and [for get()](https://github.com/samizdatco/corduroy/blob/master/corduroy/couchdb.py#L546), it looks to me like corduroy's 3-year-old code is not designed for the most modern Tornado idioms. Specifically, `get` takes a callback, rather than returning a `Future` as modern Tornado APIs do.

That means you'll have to use an older style with `gen.Task` like:

```
from tornado import gen

class RelaxedHello(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @relax
    def get(self, user_id):
        try:
            doc = yield gen.Task(people_db.get, user_id)
            self.write('hello %s'%(doc['name']))
        except NotFound:
            self.write('hello whoever you are')
        self.finish()
```

I haven't tested this, let me know how it goes. [More info on `gen.Task` is in the Tornado documentation](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/coroutines.html#interaction-with-callbacks).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I seem to remember doing something similar, but I have now stopped using Tornado, so I'll have to leave it to someone else to verify this is correct.